Is "every infinite set of strictly subnumerous sets is supernumerous to its union" equivalent to AC?
Is the following sentence equivalent to $\sf AC$ over the rest of axioms of $\sf ZF$?

For each infinite set $X$: if for all $y \in X$ we have $|y| < |X|$, then  $|  \bigcup X|\leq |X| $?

Note: The cardinality function $||$ here is defined after Scott's.
If not, then to which of the known choice principles this is equivalent to?
This comes in connection to this question.

At the very least put a link to the other question for context...

@AsafKaragila Done!

Yes, this is like Tarski's result that if $\mathfrak{c}^2=\mathfrak{c}$ for every infinite cardinal $\mathfrak{c}$, then AC holds.
In fact, it suffices to suppose that $\mathfrak{c}\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$ whenever $\mathfrak{c},\mathfrak{d}$ are cardinals and $\mathfrak{c}$ is infinite and $\mathfrak{d}<\mathfrak{c}$. (Note this follows from your hypothesis.)
For this, fix an infinite set $y$. It suffices to see that $y$ is wellorderable. We may assume that $y$ does not contain any ordinals. Let $\kappa$ be the least ordinal such that $\kappa\not\leq\mathrm{card}(y)$. Let $\mathfrak{c}=\mathrm{card}(y\bigcup\kappa)$. Then $\mathrm{card}(y)<\mathfrak{c}$, so by the hypothesis, $y\times(y\cup\kappa)$ has cardinality $y\cup\kappa$. So $y\times\kappa\leq y\cup\kappa$. But then the usual argument shows that $y$ is wellorderable, which suffices. That is, fix an injection $\pi:y\times\kappa\to y\cup\kappa$. Since $\kappa\not\leq\mathrm{card}(y)$, for each $x\in y$, there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\pi(x,\alpha)\notin y$, so $\pi(x,\alpha)\in\kappa$. Let $\alpha_x$ be the least such. Then define $f:y\to\kappa$ by setting $f(x)=\pi(x,\alpha_x)$, and note that $f$ is injective, so $y$ is wellorderable, as desired.

Very nice observation.

Do not we need the first two line of your answer? It seems to me that you proved every set is well-orderable from Zuhair's hypothesis.

@HanulJeon well, right, I didn't actually need to say that, and in the end they are both just equivalent to AC. I suppose I was just remarking that a version of the hypothesis that is superficially weaker than the original one is enough.
